# How to read one to one all images in the drawable folder

Tags: android, kotlin

I can not create a function so that when I click on the "change" button I will go through each of the images contained in my drawable folder. Any idea?

I can not find a method for my simple app to change to each of the attached images in my drawable folder

```
fun change (view: View){

        imgView_Central.setImageResource(R.drawable.car1)
    }

![My basic code](https://i.imgur.com/3J0pN7P.png)

![front side](https://i.imgur.com/wQciLhl.png)
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? Do have like a fixed number of drawable on which you want to change the displayed drawable? Explain your problem better.

Comment: Hi Archie, basically i need to change my image when i presion "change" button of my layout. In the drawable folder i have six images.

Comment: How exactly do you want that to happen? do you want a drop down to show the list of drawable you want imageview to change into? or may just cycle through that list of drawable on each click? You have to be specific.

Comment: ok, please, can you see my front side https://i.imgur.com/wQciLhl.png when i presion "change" button of my layout, the idea is that my imageView change and display each image in order, ex: car1.jpg, car2.jpg, car3.jpg, etc. then repeat again (loop). Please see this https://i.imgur.com/3J0pN7P.png (back)

Comment: So your aim is when the button is pressed, that `imageview` will cycle through your images automatically? so like every 1 second the image will change? or like every button press? this is why i am asking you to be very specific.